# Window.focus inside settimeout is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement where in i have to bring the window to focus after certain period of time i am using

```
setTimeout(window.focus,5000);

setTimeout(function()
{
window.focus
},5000);
```

but none of them are working.

Please let me know if my question is not clear

Comment: maybe change your `focus` to `focus()` it's a method

Comment: If you ever have problems with a method not working try https://developer.mozilla.org  or google 'someJavaScriptFunction mdn'

Comment: @Alexis nope.we should pass method reference

Comment: @Fast Snail. you are right we need to pass the reference.

Comment: @deekshithdeva can you make a jsfiddle live example?